# How store and retrieve image in database use laravel?

Tags: laravel

I tried some code to store an image in the database, but it's not working. So i'm enough confused to do that because i am a beginner in laravel.
Anyone can help me to solve my problem?

Here is what i'm currently doing:

```
// store image 
$this->validate($request, [ 'image' => 'image', ]);
if($request->hasFile('image')) {
    $image = $request->file('image');
    $filename = time() . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
    Image:make($image)->resize(145, 170)->save(public_path('/images' . $filename));
    $image->save(); 
};
```

Comment: Maybe show your code so we can help you find out what is going wrong.

Comment: $this->validate($request, [
            'image' => 'image',
        ]);
        
        if($request->hasFile('image')) 
        {
            $image = $request->file('image');
            $filename = time() . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
            Image:make($image)->resize(145, 170)->save(public_path('/images' . $filename));

            $image->save();
        };

Comment: @SimpleCoder put your example in a formatted way in your question. why make it hard for everyone

Comment: @SimpleCoder do you have a model named `Image` ?

Comment: @N69S Yes, i have

Answer (score 0):

the `$image` is not an instance of your `App\Image` model but an instance of `UploadedFile` class

the `Image` class is a PHP class for images

try it this way if you the attribute you want to store the path to is `path`

```
// store image 
$this->validate($request, [ 'image' => 'image', ]);
if($request->hasFile('image')) {
    $image = $request->file('image');
    $filename = time() . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
    Image::make($image)->resize(145, 170)->save(public_path('/images' . $filename));

    $imageInstance = new \App\Image();
    $imageInstance->path = '/images' . $filename;
    $imageInstance->save(); 
};
```

Comment: display a new error "Call to undefined function App\Http\Controllers\make()"

Comment: @SimpleCoder are you sure it's related to this bit of code ? there is no `$this->make()` or `self::make()` in there

Comment: here line error \Image::make($image)->resize(145, 170)->save(public_path('/images' . $filename));

Comment: remove the leading `\\`

Comment: @SimpleCoder can you post you whole controller code ?

Answer (score 0):

this sample shows how to upload multiple image

// view

```
 <form class="form-horizontal" action="{{ url('/picture-update') }}" method="post"  role="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    {{ csrf_field() }}

                <div class="col-sm-4"><label>Profile picture: </label>
                 <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="file" name="filename[]"  required> 
                        <br>
                </div>

                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-xs">Upload</button>

                </form>
```

//controller

```
public function uploadAttachment(Request $request)
    {
         $this->validate($request, [
          'filename.*' => 'mimes:pdf,doc,docx,jpeg,jpg,gif,png,bmp|max:2048',


              //processing insert into attachment table

           if($request->hasfile('filename'))
                 {
                    foreach($request->file('filename') as $file)
                    {
                       $name=$file->getClientOriginalName();
                       $file->move(public_path().'/../../yourdomain.com/attachments_files', $name);

                       DB::table('tblstaffAttachment')->insert([
                       'filepath' => $name,
                       ]);

                    }
                 }


              return back()->with('message', 'File Uploaded!');

     }
```

//route

```
Route::post('/picture-update','YourController@uploadAttachment');
```

Comment: Thanks, i will try that.